# Status of "When did you last see her"

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

[When did you last...?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1060)

Are translation questions still off-topic?
If so, the one above is translation pure and simple. (upvoted and answered....)

Comment: Does OT stand for on-topic or off-topic? )-:

Comment: ha, changed....

Answer (score 2):

While it is technically a translation (what isn't?), it's neither homework, nor do I really care about a specific sentence. I am looking for a way to express the "Most recent" point in time (possibly as a question). That is certainly not off topic, is it?

Comment: I don't *think* so.  I could imagine a "How do I refer to the most recent occurrence of something?"-like question asking about the difference between using words like 最近, 最後, or この前 (or others), which is similar to on-topic questions on the site.

Comment: That is exactly what I was going for.

Answer (score 1):

Simply based off what I see in the comments and answers, that question might be saved because there appears to be [some](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1060/when-did-you-last/1074#1074) [trouble](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1060/when-did-you-last/1070#1070) translating "last" with the same emphasis.  So maybe the question can be reworded so it fits better (building off of the idea that "last" has different connotations in English and Japanese).

Or someone can ask a better question about "last" and merge the answers.

Comment: I think it's a very straight forward translation with no special tricks. But every translation has some kind of difficulty. Nuances in even very simple sentences can be discussed for months without reaching an agreement between professionals. This is how translation works. I can find nuances and difficulties in any translation questions that have been closed until now.

Answer (score 0):

I have been wondering that, too.  I think that the question should be either made more specific or closed.